# Attach report link in TAP Extended Test Results option

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, tap

If I click on TAP Extended Test Results in Jenkins, it opens test description with status.
Is there a possibility to attach a link for a report on test description, when user clicks on it, report should be open.
[Image of TAP page ][1]
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/57183895/003.png?version=2&modificationDate=1311728708000&api=v2
or any alternative plugin for TAP

Answer (score 0):

I am new to TAP and Jenkins but I got some solution, however, i got hint from TAP Jenkins plugin page, I am sharing what I have done. 
I took the same code which was provided in the link

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15497

TAP format code should be in correct format otherwise TAP Jenkins plugin give parsing error.

here is the code:

```
1..2 
ok 1 
  ---
  extensions:
    files:
        sample.html:
         File-Type: 'text\plain'
         File-Name: 'sample.html'
         File-Size: '430'
         File-Content: bGluayBhdHRhY2g=
  ...
ok 2
```

basically, it will create a sample.html file and it will be displayed in Jenkins.

File-Content: Information provided here will be written inside 'sample.html' i.e. File-Name: 'sample.html'

Here you give the text in BASE64 encoding, which will be converted into Text. In my case, i gave the test reports link in BASE64 encoding.

Once Jenkins job is finished, TAP will display the information in page which would look like as image available in link

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15497

Click on File-Content, the file will be downloaded and it will have information which was provided. 
I could open the report after downloading the file.

Hope it helps others :)